# How to read information from file and put it back into String array?

Tags: java

I have a task where I need to read information form a file. Format of information in a file is:
London
Moscow
....
I have 7 cities and 7 rows in total. I need to read names of cities and put them back in a String array. When I test this piece of code i get a message 
`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`.

I will appreciate any ideas on how I can fix the issue.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Input {

        static Scanner keyboard, input;
        static PrintWriter output;
        static String[] namesCities;
        static String name = ""; 
        static int index;

        public static void main(String args[]) {

            try
{
            System.out.println("Please, enter the name of input file");
            keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            name = keyboard.nextLine();

            File file = new File(name);
            input = new Scanner(file);

            namesCities = new String[index];

            for (int index = 0; index < 7; index++) 
            {
                namesCities[index] = input.next();
            }
}
catch 
{

 catch (IOException a)

     { 
        System.out.println("Could not find file " + name);
        name = keyboard.nextLine();                       
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Don't use a `for` loop, use a `while` loop and check `hasNext()` on scanner. And you code can't compile because `index` is not declared when you initialise your array?

Comment: Please post the code that compiles. Your code seems to have compile time error.

Comment: Hi Anna, Welcome to the site! Just a quick tip: It's often pretty useful to include line numbers against your code, and also the entire (or at the least the top chunk) of the exception you receive. That way we can see exactly what line caused it and help you all the quicker :)

Comment: Can you show a sample of your file content? Instead of writing so much of code, you can read all lines as List using `Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(name))` and this way you don't have to deal with defining size of array and can avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Thank you everyone, I am sorry for posting piece of code that did not compile. I fixed it, it compiles but still produces out of bound exception

Comment: All your comments are great, but I am doing it such a weird way, because it is just a small part of a bigger task. And my input file is a mix of integers, strings, tables. In this case I am extracting data from particular piece of input file and simplified it here just to figure out what is going wrong with array part. I also can not use List as I have to separate all the data in to bunch of 1 and 2D arrays.

Comment: @AnnaWood: Step back and walk through your code. You initialize the array `namesCities` with `new String[index]`. This means you are essentially creating an empty array (because `index` is 0). And now you are trying to loop over it and in turn trying to access an index that clearly doesn't exist (For eg: namesCities[0], namesCities[1]...) and hence the *ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException*

Comment: Thank you, Nicholas K! I got the idea!

Answer (score 0):

In your existing code, you haven't properly initialized `index` variable due to which its value remains zero and your `namesCities = new String[index];` results in zero size array which results into `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You need to initialize it to `7` like `namesCities = new String[7];`

Avoid declaring variables at class level whose scope shouldn't last longer than needed. Like `Scanner` object or filename in your code, doesn't seem to have any value living long in fact if not properly managed, they may lead to resource leakage. Try this code which reads your file using `Files.readAllLines` in one line and returns as a `List` object where each item in list contains your line in the file. Then you can convert it to array using `toArray`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Please, enter the name of input file");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = keyboard.nextLine();
    keyboard.close();

    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(name));
    String[] nameCities = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nameCities));
}
```

Let me know if you have trouble understanding any of the code here.

Comment: It was such a good explanation!  I just needed to change the way I initialized array and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

So I wrote up something small.  This assumes you already did all the proper imports and does no actual checking to make sure the file is the right size.  If you absolutly must use a for loop you can change my loop to a for loop that goes tell counter < 7 (not counter <= 7)<---This will throw an index error.

I changed a few things but feel free to change them back,  I moved the variables inside main because you gave no reason that they should stay as instance variables.  I also changed your .nextLine() to .next() the reason is because .nextLine() cosumes everything tell it hits a new line character while .next() only goes tell it hits a white space character.  You can change both of these back to the way you had it if that is the behavior you were going for.

```
public class Input{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Please Enter the name of the input file");
        keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        name = keyboard.next();

        File file = new File(name);
        input = new Scanner(file);

        String[] nameCities = new String[7];
        int counter = 0;
        while(input.hasNext()){
            nameCities[counter] = input.next();
            counter++;
        }
        keyboard.close()//don't forget to close your scanner
    }
}
```